# Sort entries in the group and return the first one in alphabetical order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to group Dataframe and descending sort entries for a column within each group and pick the first entry.

For example:

Input Dataframe

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| First | Y |
| First | N |
| First |  |
| First | Y |
| Second | N |
| Second |  |
| Second |  |
| Second |  |
| Second | N |

The idea is to group by col1 and descending sort entries in col2 and pick the first entry. When col1 value is First, col2 values are (Y, N, NaN, Y) ---sort descending--> (Y, Y, N, NaN) --> create new col3 with first value, i.e., Y

Expected Output:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | Y | Y |
| First | N | Y |
| First |  | Y |
| First | Y | Y |
| Second | N | N |
| Second |  | N |
| Second |  | N |
| Second |  | N |
| Second | N | N |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert column to ordered Categoricals if need some custom priority order and then use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `min`:

```
df['Col2'] = pd.Categorical(df['Col2'].fillna(''), ordered=True, categories=['Y','N', ''])

df['Col2'] = df.groupby('Col1')['Col2'].transform('min')
print (df)
     Col1 Col2
0   First    Y
1   First    Y
2   First    Y
3   First    Y
4  Second    N
5  Second    N
6  Second    N
7  Second    N
8  Second    N
```

Another idea is sorting by both columns and then use [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) in [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['Col1','Col2'], ascending=[True, False])

df['Col2'] = df.groupby('Col1')['Col2'].transform('first')
print (df)
     Col1 Col2
0   First    Y
3   First    Y
1   First    Y
2   First    Y
4  Second    N
8  Second    N
5  Second    N
6  Second    N
7  Second    N
```